# Swapping odd and even bits using mips

Tags: assembly, mips

program that asks the user to enter an unsigned number and read it. Then swap the bits
at odd positions with those at even positions and display the resulting number. For example, if
the user enters the number 9, which has binary representation of 1001, then bit 0 is swapped
with bit 1, and bit 2 is swapped with bit 3, resulting in the binary number 0110. Thus, the
program should display 6.

This is only to convert decimal to binary

```
################### DATA SECTION #############################

.data

str1: .asciiz "Enter an integer please: "


.align 2

################## CODE SECTION #############################

.text

.globl main



main:

# ask and store the first number

li $v0, 4

la $a0, str1

syscall

li $v0, 5

syscall

move $a0, $v0



jal print_bin



print_bin:



add $t0, $zero, $a0 # put our input ($a0) into $t0

add $t1, $zero, $zero # Zero out $t1

addi $t3, $zero, 1 # load 1 as a mask

sll $t3, $t3, 3 # move the mask to appropriate position

addi $t4, $zero, 4 # loop counter

j loop



loop:



and $t1, $t0, $t3 # and the input with the mask

beq $t1, $zero, print # Branch to print if its 0



add $t1, $zero, $zero # Zero out $t1

addi $t1, $zero, 1 # Put a 1 in $t1

j print





print: 

li $v0, 1

move $a0, $t1

syscall



srl $t3, $t3, 1

addi $t4, $t4, -1

bne $t4, $zero, loop



move $a0, $v0
```

Comment: Have you thought about how you would accomplish this, I mean the manual steps?

Comment: I'm have the logic that I need to convert first the decimal to binary then do the swapping after. but I can only convert decimal to binary I can't do the swapping

Comment: I don't see what the current code has to do with the assignment. You don't need to convert anything to swap bits. All you need are bitwise operations like AND, OR, Shift Left, and Shift Right.

Comment: Numbers in registers are already in binary.  That's *why* a left shift multiplies by 2, not 10.  The read-integer syscall returns an int, not a string of ASCII decimal digits.